# Android Runtime Thread Attach Failed

Tags: android

When I uninstall an app using "adb uninstall , my logcat *:W starts to looks somewhat like this -

```
            W/ResourceType( 1269): Resources don't contain package for resource number 0x7f050000
            W/ResourceType( 1269): Resources don't contain package for resource number 0x7f020005
            W/ResourceType( 1269): Resources don't contain package for resource number 0x7f020004
            W/ResourceType( 1269): Resources don't contain package for resource number 0x7f0700e5
            W/ResourceType( 1269): Resources don't contain package for resource number 0x7f020031
            W/ResourceType( 1269): Resources don't contain package for resource number 0x7f020030
            W/ResourceType( 1269): Resources don't contain package for resource number 0x7f050000
            W/ResourceType( 1269): Resources don't contain package for resource number 0x7f080000
            W/ResourceType( 1269): Resources don't contain package for resource number 0x7f020051
            W/ResourceType( 1269): Resources don't contain package for resource number 0x7f020052
            W/ResourceType( 1269): Resources don't contain package for resource number 0x7f0a0000
            W/ResourceType( 1269): Resources don't contain package for resource number 0x7f02012f
            W/ResourceType( 1269): Resources don't contain package for resource number 0x7f020130
            W/ResourceType( 1269): Resources don't contain package for resource number 0x7f060001
            E/AndroidRuntime( 6887): ERROR: thread attach failed
```

What does that error - "thread attach failed" mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try killing your adb and restart it once more...

// Restarting the emulator worked for me. I guess the backup manager did not allow my application to throw RuntimeException:s. So, restarting the emulator made it forget the bad behaviour of my app. Pretty smart feature, but not well documented.

Comment: hi vinay, i have same problem and i try kill adb and start,but can solve problem. can you help me?

Comment: @niky, close your eclipse and emulator (if any open). then using task manager kill the adb. Look if it restarts in a few seconds. If so, then kill the one which is restarting (droidexplorer or similar apps will do it). Once you are sure, then open eclipse and try running.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the process ID in the log messages.  The W/ResourceType messages and the E/AndroidRuntime are in separate processes, which is usually a good indication that they are unrelated.

The "thread attach failed" messages usually come with shell commands like "adb shell am".  If they finish quickly you will see complaints because the VM is shutting down while the binder thread pool is still starting up.  The complaints are harmless.

Answer (score 0):

I received this error when trying to emulate an app on a lower VM version than specified in the manifest android:minSdkVersion.  There was also a warning I didn't see:

```
system_process  WARN    PackageParser   /data/app/vmdl34002.tmp (at Binary XML file line #6): Requires newer sdk version #8 (current version is #7)
```

Lowering the min SDK version sorted it.  A bit daft, but this might help someone else.