# Pressing button to play different .mp3 depending on spinner selection

Tags: java, android

`package com.RaffDev.RaffApp;`

`import android.app.Activity;`
`import android.media.MediaPlayer;`
`import android.os.Bundle;`
`import android.view.View;`
`import android.widget.Toast;`
`import android.widget.AdapterView;`
`import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;`
`import android.widget.Spinner;`

``` public class RaffAppActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener,``AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{ ```

```
/*Regular Variables*/
String copyright = "Raff App \n\nVersion: Alpha 0.0.1\n\n(c) Copyright Raff App contributors and others 2011. All rights reserverd";
public int soundSelection;
MediaPlayer mp;

/*Called at the beginning of the application*/
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.soundEntries, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);        
}

/*Button Functions*/
public void onClick(View v){}

public void infoClick(View v){

    Toast.makeText(this, copyright, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

public void pressPlay(View v){
    switch(soundSelection){
    case 1: 
        if(mp.isPlaying())
        mp.reset();
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.pleaseprettyface);
        mp.start();
        break;
    case 2: 
        if(mp.isPlaying())
        mp.reset();
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.sheeesh);
        mp.start();
        break;
    case 3: 
        if(mp.isPlaying())
        mp.reset();
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.heaintdodat);
        mp.start();
        break;
    case 4: 
        if(mp.isPlaying())
        mp.reset();
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.thedousky);
        mp.start();
        break;
    case 5: 
        if(mp.isPlaying())
        mp.reset();
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.nmouth);
        mp.start();
        break;


    }

}



/*Spinner Functions*/
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
    soundSelection = (Integer) parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
}

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
      // Do nothing.
}
```

}

Comment: All I get is a Force Quit message as soon as I run it. :(

Answer (score 1):

`mp` is null the first time you run this code and choose something from the spinner.  Either add a null check inside `pressPlay`, or create an instance of mp in your `onCreate()`.

Comment: case 1: 
        if(mp != null && mp.isPlaying())
        mp.reset();

Comment: I don't know why, but I'm still getting the same message. x_x

Comment: What does it say in the system logcat output?  There should be an exception there.

Comment: That error isn't important.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3421513/android-runtime-thread-attach-failed    You need to find the exception stack trace for the problem you're seeing.   It might also help to single-step through your code in the debugger.  I think you have more than one problem, and it's probably best to do all the debugging you can before asking us to do it for you.